# How can I get OAuth Access Token for Microsoft Dynamics 365 V9 using a netcore API

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, dynamics-365

I have a Aspnet Core API thats trying to connect to a Microsoft Dynamics 365 instance. The goal is to push data to the CRM Instance using an API.

In order to do this, I have a CRM User and a Pass and my understanding is I will need an OAuth token to actually complete my request.
How can I go about getting that OAuth token from an API ?

My current (non working) code looks like this:

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(CrmFInanceCCNotifyDto.Instance.CrmBaseUri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{CrmFInanceCCNotifyDto.Instance.CrmUser}:" +
                $"{CrmFInanceCCNotifyDto.Instance.CrmPass}")));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("If-Match", "*");
                var method = "PATCH";
                var httpVerb = new HttpMethod(method);
                string path = client.BaseAddress + CrmFInanceCCNotifyDto.Instance.CrmLocationUpdateUri;
                string jsonPayload = "{\"entity.dfnd_financingused\": 1}";
                var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var httpRequestMessage =
                    new HttpRequestMessage(httpVerb, path)
                    {
                        Content = stringContent
                    };
                try
                {
                    var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

Any pointers in solving this will be much appreciated.

Thanks